# image storing in mysql using php. not showing any errors but my code is not working

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a code for storing images in db, but its not getting work. anybodey can help me? my code is

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Test Page</h1>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000" />
<input type="file" name="image" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />

</form>

<?php 
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
  if(getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])== FALSE)
  {
   echo "Please select an Image";   
  }
  else
  {
   $image=addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
   $name=addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
   $image=file_get_contents($image);
   $image=base64_encode($image);
   saveimage($name,$image);
  }
 }
 function saveimage($name,$image)
 {
  include 'conn.php';
  $qry="INSERT INTO topic_images(echcode,topi_num,img_num,img,iname) VALUES('test001','01','01','$image','$name')";
  $result=mysql_query($qry,$link);
  if($result)
  {
   echo "<br/> uploaded successfully"; 
  }
  else
  {
   echo "<br/> not uploaded"; 
  }
 }

?>


</body>
</html>
```

how can correct this. this is always shopwing not uploaded. and not getting uploaded. anybody can help me? awaiting your replies.. and the thing is that i am a beginner.

Comment: `Suggestion` : Instead of storing image into database just store image reference (Path) and upload image to folder using move_uploaded_file()

Comment: Put your error reporting on. Add this after opening your php tag: ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

Comment: its like a social site so i think it's not a good way to store path only..

Comment: i have added the above mentioned code also.. but no response... you know why?

Comment: Have you ever thought what will happen if your image size is too large. I think the better approach is to store image reference. But still if you want to store image than you can store in BLOB datatype by getting file contents.

Comment: Add following line if you get any MySQL error `$result=mysql_query($qry,$link) or die(mysql_error())`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `$result` is false, which would often indicate a problem with the MySQL query (assuming you were able to previously connect to and select the database).

PHP will not print MySQL errors by default, if I remember well. So you need to find out any MySQL error in another way.

Try running this just before echoing "not uploaded":

```
echo mysql_error();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Another thing you can try, is echo the query itself (`$qry`) before executing it, and then copy it, paste it into an SQL client and run it there, you should be able to see any errors and be in a better environment for fixing them. But...

If you are doing that, make sure you upload a very, very small image (like 1K or less maybe), or maybe upload a small text file instead of an image, otherwise the printed query will be huge and might even crash your browser.

BTW, if this is code that you are developing right now, I think you should use mysqli_ functions instead of deprecated mysql_ functions.